# get element and attribute with filename for XML from java

Tags: java

I have 10 xml files in some folders like below, I want to process all files and get file name with element and attribute name:

```
   abc.xml 

     <bank xsi:SchemaLocation="roll.xsd" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>

   sss.xml


     <bank xsi:SchemaLocation="cust.xsd" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
```

I want to extract file name, element name with attribute value, like:

```
     abc.xml bank roll.xsd
     sss.xml bank cust.xsd
```

I have written code but my code is not working for all file and not getting attribute value also:

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import java.io.File;

public class aaaaa {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

    File fXmlFile = new File("/Users/rtyu/*.xml");
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
    NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("bank");
    System.out.println("----------------------------");
    for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
        Node nNode = nList.item(temp);          
        System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());
        if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
            System.out.println("attribute value : " + eElement.getAttribute("xsi"));
        }
    }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: Yes, i did, but i am getting only element name from only 1 file and not attribute name. and i am not able to process all file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you specify only namespace `xsi` instead of tag name.

Change `eElement.getAttribute("xsi")` to `eElement.getAttribute("xsi:SchemaLocation")` and it will work.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        File fXmlFile = new File("/Users/rtyu/*.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("bank");
        System.out.println("----------------------------");
        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
            System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());
            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                System.out.println("attribute value : " + eElement.getAttribute("xsi:SchemaLocation"));
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried but not working: 

public static void main(String[] args) {
  File fXmlFile = new File("/Users/rtyu/*.xml");
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
    System.out.println("Attribute: " + doc.getAttribute("xsi:SchemaLocation"));
  
     } catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
     }
   }

Comment: You don't need to change anything else as you did. I update an answer with code snippet.

Comment: Thank you so much, yes now i am getting attribute also with element name. But that is for individual file. Like i have 10 xml and want then how to get from there *.xml